# Hibernate not working even with a swap partition on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, swap, hibernate

I've looked at a couple of posts and they haven't helped me resolve this issue.

I run:

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

And upon starting it again, nothing is saved.

Here's my swap partition:

```
sudo swapon --show
/dev/dm-3 partition 15.9G   0B   -1
```

Here's the output of `free`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       16347964      933220    14233316      228152     1181428    14860484
Swap:      16694780           0    16694780
```

my fstab:

```
grep swap /etc/fstab
#/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

I've also done a `sudo apt purge btrfs-tools`, but it said none was installed.

If you need any more information, let me know.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Have you tried the answers here: [How can I hibernate on Ubuntu 16.04?](//askubuntu.com/q/768136)?

Comment: @Zanna yep, was the first thing I looked

Comment: @Pilot6 Can't seem to find that on my laptop. It's a Toshiba Satellite.

Comment: I don't suppose that my hard drive being encrypted would affect it either?

Comment: Yes, if swap is encrypted, hibernation doesn't work.

Comment: @Pilot6 might be the reason why then >< I reinstalled the OS without any encryption and it seems to work now :) Thanks